NE567 supply voltage
The below image lists supply voltages for NE series ICs:

Figure 1: supply voltage
Why is the IC supply voltage given as absolute positive voltage (some in thelist specify +/- values) rather than a relative one? If voltages are only scales, what is the significance here of only positive values?

Figure 2: NE567 internal schematic
(Above 2 images from: Internet Archive - bitsavers.org collection - signetics ::  dataBooks :: 1972 Signetics PLL Applications (direct PDF link))
Are there any special components that can source or sink only? I don't have that much expertise. The schematic of the NE567 is included above.
For example most CD series IC's like CD4066,etc tell  supply voltage as 3to18 v and I mostly use them with +/-5V,haven't faced any problem.
In the same can I supply NE567 with+/-4.5V.if yes why it isnt  mentioned in bipolar terms like they have did it for NE565 in the table.

In a comment:

all voltages are ground referenced to AC mains ground

That's false. They are referenced in a way that makes sense in the particular part of the system.
Sometimes you have a system with just a battery and a single IC that is not referenced to "AC ground" (really PE terminal).
Sometimes you have a system whose parts "float" on high voltages, e.g. the output section of a high-side gate driver. The supply voltage of the high-side driver may be fairly low, say 12V, but it's referenced to the source terminal of the MOSFET which may be 400V above the power ground of the system. That power ground then may be connected to the mains outlet PE terminal. Or not. In an electric car running on battery down the road, it wouldn't be :)

Why is the IC supply voltage given as absolute positive voltage (some in the list specify +/- values) rather than a relative one?

Relative voltages can be positive or negative. So when you read +24V, it doesn't indicate whether it's absolute or relative. There is no such thing as an "absolute" voltage anyway - it's by definition relative, a difference of two potentials. So you're asking a question about a strawman - something you made up, more-or-less.
In the case of those PLL chips, the "bipolar" supply voltages are indicative of typical application where the PLL interfaces with digital logic, for example, and it's convenient to supply it with symmetric supplies. That's some of them run from ±5V: the positive supply is the logic supply.
But those PLL chips only have two power supply terminals - no GND terminal. Thus, a specification of ±5V means that there's +10V between the V+ and V- terminals.

I think the main question is: can he run the NE567 using +4.5 on V+ and -4.5 on GND. According to the chart, they explicitly went out of their way to say +9V instead of +/-4.5V. Also, they explicitly have it labeled GND instead of VSS or VEE. These make me think that there’s something in the circuitry that would be sensitive to not have GND pin at 0V. I tried looking at the transistor level schematic in the datasheet but could not see anything that stands out to me, but I’m bad at IC level stuff so I think it’s beyond my abilities. Is it something you can take a look at?

@steKulov that's exactly matches what I asking

@SteKulov There is no GND pin :)

So here PLL IC mentioned in bipolar terms,as with bipolar the lock condition output is easier to process with further digital logic in the chain.So all IC in the list can be operated with bipolar or unipolar voltage with no degradation in performance. System level interface to be taken care when selecting what type of supply to be used,just this,nothing more hiding in those specs?

I'm sorry.  I meant the "GROUND" pin.  MY BAD!  https://i.sstatic.net/eAkZ2d6v.png

The supply voltage range is simply that for which the IC was designed. As shown in the NE567 schematic, the circuit was designed to be supplied by a positive voltage on pin 4 with ground connected to pin 7. Other ICs in the series were designed to use both positive and negative supplies.

Every now then I hear voltage is only reference scale,in that case is +9v here same as +/-4.5 v just a different representation.can ground pin connected to -4.5v and supply to +4.5v here(all voltage are ground reference to AC mains ground)

Let's take a step back first, as you're not asking how to use that IC - you're asking why voltages are expressed that way in electronics engineering...
Electronics engineering consists of two separate things: electronics and engineering. Electronics is the theoretical subject. Engineering is the practical application of a subject by groups of humans to build things that solve real-world problems.
In electronics, a voltage measurement is the relative voltage difference between two points. In an isolated system, each point's voltage magnitudes could be expressed as any numerical values so long as they have the required difference. So if there was 9 V between two points, the voltages at those points could indeed be expressed as 9V/0V, as 2000V/1991V, as -300V/-309V and so on. All other voltages throughout the isolated system would then have to be stated relative to those voltages, but it would work arithmetically.
But in engineering, a circuit should be as easy to recognise and understand as possible by all of the relevant design, test, production, sales and service staff. The circuit is nearly always connected to other circuits so a common standard for their interfaces is preferable, so (a) problems with that scheme can be identified and minimised, and (b) people can re-use what they've learned, working faster by recognising familiar things i.e. de facto standards.

In your question's example IC, all of the voltages are referenced to an expected 0 V rail. By manufactured volume, most electronics circuits call a common rail 0 V and reference all of their voltages to it. By choosing the easiest value to calculate with (zero), the mental arithmetic on the other voltages is eased. In other words, why pick something else that's more difficult to work with and has no benefit?
You'll find similar points of view on the use a common reference throughout much of engineering.
